# jqGrid Drag and Drop Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

jqGrid has a feature that you can drag and drop columns from one table into another table. It can be seen at http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html under `New in version 3.6` under `Drag and Drop Rows`

I have two main problems. First of them when I remove a row from one table to another table row id changes(may be its jquery-ui's feature). It can be inspected from trirand's example. Second of them is I loose one of my columns at every move(I will provide more information about second problem)

Any ideas?

Comment: There are different `gridDnD` options which you can use (`autoid` as function for example). If you describe a problem like disappear of columns you should include the definition of the both grids and the call of `gridDnD` method which you currently use.

Comment: @Oleg thanks for your response. When I talk about my first problem, I did that: I made autoid to false. However this time it started to give different ids to my dropped rows as like: jqg1, jqg2, jqg3.. (It was dnd_auto number - you can drag and drop and inspect tr id at firebug from trirand's web site)

Comment: I suggested that you define `autoid` as function and not as boolean. Only after you will post the definition of the grids one can write any example of `autoid`.